# Is this the correct syntax for CMD Shift Down?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

Is this the correct syntax for <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> in Sikuli?

```
type(keyDown, KeyModifier.CMD | KeyModifier.SHIFT)
```

I've already tried the following but they don't seem to work:

```
type(keyDown, KeyModifier.CMD + KeyModifier.SHIFT)
type(KeyModifier.CMD, KeyModifier.SHIFT, keyDown)
type(keyDown, KeyModifier.CMD | KeyModifier.SHIFT)
```

I'd like this code to highlight text from a starting highlight all the way down the page.

Prior to this code I'm using doubleClick('Image of area that's double clicked')

The image that's double clicked in this case is the whitespace before the word 'Description' and the word 'Description combined.

Answer (score 0):

Such questions should be asked on SikuliX's Launchpad Q&A forum.

type(keyDown, KeyModifier.CMD | KeyModifier.SHIFT)

is principally correct, but there is a problem with the NUM-Lock state:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/894312